# Matching words from two files and extract matched one

Tags: regex, r, pattern-matching

I have following data frame:

```
dataFrame <- data.frame(sent = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5), word = c("good printer", "wireless easy", "just right size",
                                                          "size perfect weight", "worth price", "website great tablet",
                                                          "pan nice tablet", "great price", "product easy install"), val = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
```

Data frame "**dataFrame**" looks like below:

```
sent                word  val
  1         good printer   1
  1        wireless easy   2
  2      just right size   3
  2  size perfect weight   4
  3          worth price   5
  3 website great tablet   6
  3      pan nice tablet   7
  4          great price   8
  5 product easy install   9
```

And then I have words:

```
nouns <- c("printer", "wireless", "weight", "price", "tablet")
```

I need to extract only these words (**nouns**) from **dataFrame** and only these extracted add to new column (eg.extract) in **dataFrame**.

I really very appreciate any of your help od advice. Thanks a lot in forward.

Desired output:

```
  sent                word  val   extract
    1         good printer   1    printer
    1        wireless easy   2    wireless
    2      just right size   3    size
    2  size perfect weight   4    weight
    3          worth price   5    price
    3 website great tablet   6    table
    3      pan nice tablet   7    tablet
    4          great price   8    price
    5 product easy install   9    remove this row (no match)
```

Comment: Didn't you ask a very similar question an hour ago?  How did you respond to its comments?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344070/extracting-words-from-sentence-which-match-with-words-in-dictionary

Comment: I've closed that other question, please don't post same question twice.

Comment: sorry for that, was wondered about changing the task and unfortunately replicated that one.

Comment: interesting question! I was wondering that you need to be sure that only a single noun can occur for every cell in your word column.

Comment: Actually discovered that the @David Arenburg solution automatically provides a second column in the case two words in the noun list match, for example if dataFrame[5,2] had the value "tablet price" instead of "worth price". Nice solution!

Comment: David, how should I change your source code, if I want exact match? E.g. in sent 1, when I change good printering so in extract column I need <NA>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using the `stringi` package (`size` isn't in your `nouns` list btw).

```
library(stringi)
transform(dataFrame, 
          extract = stri_extract_all(word, 
          regex = paste(nouns, collapse = "|"), 
          simplify = TRUE))

#   sent                 word val  extract
# 1    1         good printer   1  printer
# 2    1        wireless easy   2 wireless
# 3    2      just right size   3     <NA>
# 4    2  size perfect weight   4   weight
# 5    3          worth price   5    price
# 6    3 website great tablet   6   tablet
# 7    3      pan nice tablet   7   tablet
# 8    4          great price   8    price
# 9    5 product easy install   9     <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is another solution. a bit more complicated but it also deletes the rows which have no matching between nouns and dataFrame$word

```
require(stringr)
dataFrame <- data.frame("sent" = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5),
                            "word" = c("good printer", "wireless easy", "just right size",
                                       "size perfect weight", "worth price", "website great tablet",
                                       "pan nice tablet", "great price", "product easy install"),
                            val = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))

    nouns <- c("printer", "wireless", "weight", "price", "tablet")

    test <- character()
    df.del <- list()

    for (i in 1:nrow(dataFrame)) {
        if(length(intersect(nouns, unlist(strsplit(as.character(dataFrame$word[i]), " ")))) == 0) {
            df.del <- rbind(df.del, i)
        } else {
            test <- rbind(test,
                          intersect(nouns, unlist(strsplit(as.character(dataFrame$word[i]), " "))))
        }
    }

    dataFrame <- dataFrame[-c(unlist(df.del)), ]
    dataFrame <- cbind(dataFrame, test)
    names(dataFrame)[4] <- "extract"
```

output:

```
  sent                 word val  extract
1    1         good printer   1  printer
2    1        wireless easy   2 wireless
4    2  size perfect weight   4   weight
5    3          worth price   5    price
6    3 website great tablet   6   tablet
7    3      pan nice tablet   7   tablet
8    4          great price   8    price
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using loop function and if statement.

```
word<-dataFrame$word
dat<-NULL
extract<-c(rep(c("remove"), each=length(word)))
n<-length(word) 
m<-length(nouns)

for (i in 1:n) {
g<-as.character(word[i])
for (j in 1:m) {
dat<-grepl(nouns[j], g)
if(dat == TRUE) {extract[i] <- nouns[j]} 
}
}

dataFrame$extract <- extract

#  sent                 word val  extract
#1    1         good printer   1  printer
#2    1        wireless easy   2 wireless
#3    2      just right size   3   remove
#4    2  size perfect weight   4   weight
#5    3          worth price   5    price
#6    3 website great tablet   6   tablet
#7    3      pan nice tablet   7   tablet
#8    4          great price   8    price
#9    5 product easy install   9   remove
```